# can we able to get server configuration using client instance in hazelcast?

Tags: java, server, client, hazelcast

I need to get the configuration of the server using the instance of the client in hazelcast. I have tried lots of methods.But nothing went right..

Is there any way to do so??

Answer (score 1):

There is.

In short. Create a Callable, implement HazelcastInstanceAware interface so you can access the HazelcastInstance (serverside instance). Once you have the instance, you can call HazelcastInstance.getConfig. This is what the callable is going to return.

From the client you shoot this Callable into a random member of cluster using IExecutorService.submit and then you Config config = future.get() and you have your Config.

Comment: This is a very helpful hint. However, on trying I am getting `There is no suitable serializer for class com.hazelcast.internal.dynamicconfig.DynamicConfigurationAwareConfig`. Does that mean I cannot possibly bring Config object over the wire? Using Hazelcast 4.0.2